# Get the treeCell Implementation using the treeItem in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am implementing drag and drag between two tree views. When a treeItem is dropped onto another treeView of treeItem a line connection is established between the two treeItems. This is working fine , but to have a connection initially without a drag and drop events is problem to me.
    I am using treeCell for the drag and drop events.

Comment: This seems like it would be pretty difficult. I wonder if a `TreeView` is really what you want here; the cell mechanism is really not designed for this kind of behavior. How are you going to manage your line connections if the cell at one end of the line is removed from the `TreeView` because its parent node is collapsed? What if it is scrolled out of view (the `TreeItem` would potentially not have a cell associated with it)?

Comment: I implemented without the use of treeCell , But it is not a proper way of implementation. A line should be drawn using the two nodes. In this case nodes are cell. If u have suggestion it would be great. and thanks your reply

Comment: I can't really make a suggestion: I don't know how I would get past the requirement problems I outlined above. If you can update the question to address the problems with the requirements, I might be able to make some implementation suggestions.

Comment: The problem is establishing connection pro-grammatically between the two treeItems. This is the requirement. I need layout position of the treeItems in the treeView which is possible only with the help of treeCell. I am not getting a way to get a instance of TreeCell of a particular treeItem.

Comment: Again, you can't implement this without answering questions like: what will you do if you have an existing connection between two `TreeItem`s, and the cell for one of the `TreeItem`s is reused for another `TreeItem`? There is no way to suggest an implementation until you address those issues as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I thought, this turns out to be pretty difficult.

There is, by design, no way to get the `TreeCell` belonging to a given `TreeItem`. This is because of the "virtualization" design of the `TreeView`: a minimal number of `TreeCell`s are created and these are updated with new `TreeItem`s as required. Thus there typically won't be a `TreeCell` for every `TreeItem`, and the `TreeItem` represented by a given `TreeCell` may change at any point.

To make this work, first create an observable collection storing all the connections between the trees (e.g. an `ObservableSet` should work well). Represent the connections by some class that exposes start and end points which can be used for the lines.

Create custom cell factories for the trees. The cells they return should:

1. observe the item they are representing. If the item changes to one that is at an end of one or more connections, then the appropriate point on those connections should be bound to the appropriate transform of the coordinates of the cell.
2. If the item changes **from** one that is at the end of one or more connections, then unbind the appropriate end from the cell coordinates
3. observe the observable collection of connections. If one is added for which this cell's item is one end, then bind the coordinates as above

Note that when you bind the coordinates, you need to take into account the fact that the cells may move (e.g. via scrolling or via other changes in GUI layout). You also need to transform the coordinates from the cell's own coordinate system into the coordinate system of whichever pane is holding the connections (obviously, if these are connecting one tree to another, it must be some common scene graph ancestor of both trees).

And finally, you need some housekeeping. The connections need to make sure they either become invisible, or are removed from the scene if they are no longer bound at one or more ends.

I created [an example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/3da84819033a03db1496). I just created some simple controls for generating the connections, but you could easily do this with drag and drop instead. The class encapsulating the view of the connection is `AssignmentView`; it uses `Assignment` to represent the actual data that is connected. The `ConnectedTrees` class is the main application and most of the interesting controller-type work is in there. The remaining classes are just data representation. The example is all Java 8; I think it would be much uglier in JavaFX 2.2.

Comment: But there is still a case is pending, :-  connection is not updating according to the position of  the treeItem cell.

Comment: The example I linked seemed to work fine, both on scrolling and when tree nodes above the connected node were expanded and collapsed. If it doesn't work for your use case, try experimenting with the properties to which listeners are attached in the anonymous constructor in the `bindLocations(...)` method

Comment: When the treeItem is collapsed, its child treeItem connections are still visible.

Comment: And  when the treeView is scrolled down connection with other treeView item is updating not the scrolled treeViewed

Comment: Are you referring to the [example I posted](https://gist.github.com/james-d/3da84819033a03db1496)? All that is working just fine for me: collapsing nodes, scrolling, etc. Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Thank u so much...for ur example.. it helped me a lot lot... and i am using Java7,  only collapse and expand were not working,,, but sm hw i made it to happen

Answer (score 5):

```java
final var treeCells = treeView.lookupAll( ".tree-cell" );
final var cells = new ArrayList<>( treeCells );
final var row = treeView.getRow( n );
final var node = cells.get( row );
if( node instanceof TreeCell ) {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  final var cell = (TreeCell) node;
  System.out.println( "TREE CELL: " + cell );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses recursion calls to traverse the nodes tree of the tree view.
Normally this recursion shouldn't be dangerous as there is only limited nodes number (`TreeCell`'s instances are reused by `TreeView`):

```
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;

import java.util.List;

public class TreeViewExplore {

    /**
     * Returns a cell for the tree item given. Or null.
     *
     * @param treeItem tree item
     * @param treeView tree view
     * @return tree cell
     */
    public static TreeCell findCellByItem(TreeItem treeItem, TreeView treeView) {
        return recursiveFindCellByItem(treeItem, treeView);
    }

    private static TreeCell recursiveFindCellByItem(TreeItem treeItem, Node node) {

        if (node.getStyleClass().contains("tree-cell")
                && TreeCell.class.isAssignableFrom(node.getClass())
                && ((TreeCell) node).getTreeItem() == treeItem)
            return (TreeCell) node;

        if (!Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(node.getClass()))
            return null;

        List<Node> nodes = ((Parent) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable();
        if (nodes == null) return null;

        for (Node n : nodes) {
            TreeCell cell = recursiveFindCellByItem(treeItem, n);
            if (cell != null) return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// TreeItem treeItem = ...

TreeCell cell = TreeViewExplore.findCellByItem(treeItem, treeView);

// Check result:
System.out.println(
        cell == null ? "cell is null" :
                "(cell.getTreeItem() == treeItem) = "
                        + (cell.getTreeItem() == treeItem));
```

Yet another solution using `lookupAll()` method. It is only for example here as it looks non very efficient for me because this method collects all nodes with CSS-selector given (and traverses all over the tree in any case):

```
public static TreeCell findCellByItem(TreeItem treeItem, TreeView treeView) {
    return (TreeCell) treeView.lookupAll(".tree-cell").stream()
            .filter(n -> ((TreeCell) n).getTreeItem() == treeItem)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```