# Get TreeCell implementation using treeItem in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have treeItem in treeview, But i need treeCell implmentation of the treeView. How to get the tree Cell implementation of tree Item?

Comment: Use a `CellFactory` http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-tableview-cell-renderer/

Comment: Using cell factory we will not get instance of the cell implmentation

Comment: Why do you need it? This is probably not what you want to do: for one thing, not every `TreeItem` has a `TreeCell` associated to it, and for another, even if you get a reference to the `TreeCell`, the `TreeItem` it displays is liable to change. It's possible to solve whatever you're trying to do using a cell factory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the treeCell Implementation using the treeItem in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490690/get-the-treecell-implementation-using-the-treeitem-in-javafx)

Comment: I need treecell height,